# Не подключается файл скрипта (или не срабатывает)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var sum = 0,
  mon = 0;

$('#sum').slider({
  min: 0.1,
  max: 5,
  step: 0.05,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    sum = ui.value;
    calc(sum, mon)
  }
});
$('#mon').slider({
  min: 2,
  max: 12,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    mon = ui.value;
    calc(sum, mon)
  }
});

function calc(sum, mon) {
  $('#get').val((sum * (1 + (0.025 * mon))).toFixed(2));
  $('#sumv').html(sum);
  $('#monv').html(mon);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Сумма вклада</td>
      <td>
        <div id="sum">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td id="sumv">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Срок, мес.</td>
      <td>
        <div id="mon">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td id="monv">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Сумма по окончанию вклада</td>
      <td><input id="get" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="/assets/js/calc.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю как вставить ссылку на jsfiddle. На скрине видно что должно получатся, но у меня то, что идет при нажатии на "выполнить код".
В чем проблема?
Спасибо

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не отображаются ползунки и цифры и т.п.?

Comment: Поясните суть вашего вопроса. Добавьте больше деталей по вашей проблеме. Где возникает ошибка, текст ошибки и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

А вы точно подключили файлы библиотеки для слайдера? Если я правильно понял, то это слайдер - [slider | jquery ui](https://jqueryui.com/slider/)

Скорее всего Вы их не подключили:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`
И - `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

upd: поправил ссылку на стили

Comment: Так и есть......